# bdist_rpm from Ubuntu to CentOs

Tags: python, ubuntu, centos, rpm

We develop on Ubuntu/Macs and deploy RPMs to CentOS (this is the settings, can't be changed much).

The problem is that when installing from the rpm, the packages go to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (which is the right location for Ubuntu). However the default python path in CentOS is looking at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Is there a way to tell bdist_rpm where to install the files to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `setup.cfg` file to override the Python lib install path:

**setup.cfg**:

```
[install]
install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Example:

```
% python setup.py bdist_rpm
% rpm -qpl dist/foo-0.0.0-1.noarch.rpm | grep foo

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/__init__.pyc
```