# Python distutils - Change Path RPM Installs To

Tags: python, rpm, distutils, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have Python 2.7.5 and am using distutils (`python setup.py bdist_rpm`) to create the following RPM...

```
me@hostname:/tmp/dist$ rpm -qpil myApp-2.0.146-1.noarch.rpm
Name        : myApp
Version     : 2.0.146
Release     : 1
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Development/Libraries
Size        : 290576
License     : GPL
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : myApp-2.0.146-1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Wed 15 Oct 2014 02:57:08 PM EDT
Build Host  : hostname.example.lan
Relocations : /usr
Vendor      : Me <me@example.lan>
URL         : https://otherhost.example.lan/myApp
Summary     : My application
Description :
My application
/tmp/myApp/CHANGELOG
/tmp/myApp/README
/tmp/myApp/some.sh
/tmp/myApp/some.py
/tmp/myApp/libs/another.py
/tmp/myApp/libs/another.sh
...
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when the RPM is installed the files get put in...

```
/usr/local/bin/CHANGELOG
/usr/local/bin/README
/usr/local/bin/some.sh
/usr/local/bin/some.py
/usr/local/bin/libs/another.py
/usr/local/bin/libs/another.sh
...
```

...rather than in /tmp.

Yes, I understand the *locations* may be wrong/sub-par/unconventional/not-best-practice/dumb/whatev in your eyes but this is the way it has to be.  I just can't figure out how to do it.  Is there something I could/should do in my distutils `setup()` (maybe when I am populating `data_files` parameter of `setup()`?  This shouldn't matter but I will share the following simply to convey I have flexibility in calling `setup()`.  My `setup.py` is created dynamically by another Python script and then run by the other script via `subprocess`.

I don't know that it's possible to "pause" `setup.py` so I can manipulate the spec file.  I can't `chroot` to fake things.  Not sure how to handle this but it seems it should be simple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer: Rather than dynamically generating setup.py and using distutils (which seems to have some limitations) I now generate an rpmbuild .spec and can do what I need.

Cheers.

Comment: This is definetly not the answer about how to achieve it using `setuptools`

Comment: @Ordiel, I didn't see any proposed answers that worked including from you.  I did what I did and it worked so it must be an answer.  Furthermore, I didn't mention `setuptools`, so your comment is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6220687/725021

You should try the `install-lib` paramater of the `[install]` section in `setup.cfg`.